# Bootstrap tree view color changes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-treeview to show menus and submenus in tree structure.
https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

By default for the menus with sub menus an icon is appearing left to the menu and when we click on that icon it is expanding.

How to change icon placement from left to right and also apply some background color for the submenus shown after clicking the menu?

Bootstrap-tree view:

```
!function(a,b,c,d){"use strict";var e="treeview",f={};f.settings={injectStyle:!0,levels:2,expandIcon:"glyphicon glyphicon-plus",collapseIcon:"glyphicon glyphicon-minus",emptyIcon:"glyphicon",nodeIcon:"",selectedIcon:"",checkedIcon:"glyphicon glyphicon-check",uncheckedIcon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",color:d,backColor:d,borderColor:d,onhoverColor:"#F5F5F5",selectedColor:"#FFFFFF",selectedBackColor:"#428bca",searchResultColor:"#D9534F",searchResultBackColor:d,enableLinks:!1,highlightSelected:!0,highlightSearchResults:!0,showBorder:!0,showIcon:!0,showCheckbox:!1,showTags:!1,multiSelect:!1,onNodeChecked:d,onNodeCollapsed:d,onNodeDisabled:d,onNodeEnabled:d,onNodeExpanded:d,onNodeSelected:d,onNodeUnchecked:d,onNodeUnselected:d,onSearchComplete:d,onSearchCleared:d},f.options={silent:!1,ignoreChildren:!1},f.searchOptions={ignoreCase:!0,exactMatch:!1,revealResults:!0};var g=function(b,c){return this.$element=a(b),this.elementId=b.id,this.styleId=this.elementId+"-style",this.init(c),{options:this.options,init:a.proxy(this.init,this),remove:a.proxy(this.remove,this),getNode:a.proxy(this.getNode,this),getParent:a.proxy(this.getParent,this),getSiblings:a.proxy(this.getSiblings,this),getSelected:a.proxy(this.getSelected,this),getUnselected:a.proxy(this.getUnselected,this),getExpanded:a.proxy(this.getExpanded,this),getCollapsed:a.proxy(this.getCollapsed,this),getChecked:a.proxy(this.getChecked,this),getUnchecked:a.proxy(this.getUnchecked,this),getDisabled:a.proxy(this.getDisabled,this),getEnabled:a.proxy(this.getEnabled,this),selectNode:a.proxy(this.selectNode,this),unselectNode:a.proxy(this.unselectNode,this),toggleNodeSelected:a.proxy(this.toggleNodeSelected,this),collapseAll:a.proxy(this.collapseAll,this),collapseNode:a.proxy(this.collapseNode,this),expandAll:a.proxy(this.expandAll,this),expandNode:a.proxy(this.expandNode,this),toggleNodeExpanded:a.proxy(this.toggleNodeExpanded,this),revealNode:a.proxy(this.revealNode,this),checkAll:a.proxy(this.checkAll,this),checkNode:a.proxy(this.checkNode,this),uncheckAll:a.proxy(this.uncheckAll,this),uncheckNode:a.proxy(this.uncheckNode,this),toggleNodeChecked:a.proxy(this.toggleNodeChecked,this),disableAll:a.proxy(this.disableAll,this),disableNode:a.proxy(this.disableNode,this),enableAll:a.proxy(this.enableAll,this),enableNode:a.proxy(this.enableNode,this),toggleNodeDisabled:a.proxy(this.toggleNodeDisabled,this),search:a.proxy(this.search,this),clearSearch:a.proxy(this.clearSearch,this)}};g.prototype.init=function(b){this.tree=[],this.nodes=[],b.data&&("string"==typeof b.data&&(b.data=a.parseJSON(b.data)),this.tree=a.extend(!0,[],b.data),delete b.data),this.options=a.extend({},f.settings,b),this.destroy(),this.subscribeEvents(),this.setInitialStates({nodes:this.tree},0),this.render()},g.prototype.remove=function(){this.destroy(),a.removeData(this,e),a("#"+this.styleId).remove()},g.prototype.destroy=function(){this.initialized&&(this.$wrapper.remove(),this.$wrapper=null,this.unsubscribeEvents(),this.initialized=!1)},g.prototype.unsubscribeEvents=function(){this.$element.off("click"),this.$element.off("nodeChecked"),this.$element.off("nodeCollapsed"),this.$element.off("nodeDisabled"),this.$element.off("nodeEnabled"),this.$element.off("nodeExpanded"),this.$element.off("nodeSelected"),this.$element.off("nodeUnchecked"),this.$element.off("nodeUnselected"),this.$element.off("searchComplete"),this.$element.off("searchCleared")},g.prototype.subscribeEvents=function(){this.unsubscribeEvents(),this.$element.on("click",a.proxy(this.clickHandler,this)),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeChecked&&this.$element.on("nodeChecked",this.options.onNodeChecked),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeCollapsed&&this.$element.on("nodeCollapsed",this.options.onNodeCollapsed),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeDisabled&&this.$element.on("nodeDisabled",this.options.onNodeDisabled),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeEnabled&&this.$element.on("nodeEnabled",this.options.onNodeEnabled),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeExpanded&&this.$element.on("nodeExpanded",this.options.onNodeExpanded),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeSelected&&this.$element.on("nodeSelected",this.options.onNodeSelected),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeUnchecked&&this.$element.on("nodeUnchecked",this.options.onNodeUnchecked),"function"==typeof this.options.onNodeUnselected&&this.$element.on("nodeUnselected",this.options.onNodeUnselected),"function"==typeof this.options.onSearchComplete&&this.$element.on("searchComplete",this.options.onSearchComplete),"function"==typeof this.options.onSearchCleared&&this.$element.on("searchCleared",this.options.onSearchCleared)},g.prototype.setInitialStates=function(b,c){if(b.nodes){c+=1;var d=b,e=this;a.each(b.nodes,function(a,b){b.nodeId=e.nodes.length,b.parentId=d.nodeId,b.hasOwnProperty("selectable")||(b.selectable=!0),b.state=b.state||{},b.state.hasOwnProperty("checked")||(b.state.checked=!1),b.state.hasOwnProperty("disabled")||(b.state.disabled=!1),b.state.hasOwnProperty("expanded")||(!b.state.disabled&&c<e.options.levels&&b.nodes&&b.nodes.length>0?b.state.expanded=!0:b.state.expanded=!1),b.state.hasOwnProperty("selected")||(b.state.selected=!1),e.nodes.push(b),b.nodes&&e.setInitialStates(b,c)})}},g.prototype.clickHandler=function(b){this.options.enableLinks||b.preventDefault();var c=a(b.target),d=this.findNode(c);if(d&&!d.state.disabled){var e=c.attr("class")?c.attr("class").split(" "):[];-1!==e.indexOf("expand-icon")?(this.toggleExpandedState(d,f.options),this.render()):-1!==e.indexOf("check-icon")?(this.toggleCheckedState(d,f.options),this.render()):(d.selectable?this.toggleSelectedState(d,f.options):this.toggleExpandedState(d,f.options),this.render())}},g.prototype.findNode=function(a){var b=a.closest("li.list-group-item").attr("data-nodeid"),c=this.nodes[b];return c||console.log("Error: node does not exist"),c},g.prototype.toggleExpandedState=function(a,b){a&&this.setExpandedState(a,!a.state.expanded,b)},g.prototype.setExpandedState=function(b,c,d){c!==b.state.expanded&&(c&&b.nodes?(b.state.expanded=!0,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeExpanded",a.extend(!0,{},b))):c||(b.state.expanded=!1,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeCollapsed",a.extend(!0,{},b)),b.nodes&&!d.ignoreChildren&&a.each(b.nodes,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setExpandedState(b,!1,d)},this))))},g.prototype.toggleSelectedState=function(a,b){a&&this.setSelectedState(a,!a.state.selected,b)},g.prototype.setSelectedState=function(b,c,d){c!==b.state.selected&&(c?(this.options.multiSelect||a.each(this.findNodes("true","g","state.selected"),a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setSelectedState(b,!1,d)},this)),b.state.selected=!0,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeSelected",a.extend(!0,{},b))):(b.state.selected=!1,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeUnselected",a.extend(!0,{},b))))},g.prototype.toggleCheckedState=function(a,b){a&&this.setCheckedState(a,!a.state.checked,b)},g.prototype.setCheckedState=function(b,c,d){c!==b.state.checked&&(c?(b.state.checked=!0,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeChecked",a.extend(!0,{},b))):(b.state.checked=!1,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeUnchecked",a.extend(!0,{},b))))},g.prototype.setDisabledState=function(b,c,d){c!==b.state.disabled&&(c?(b.state.disabled=!0,this.setExpandedState(b,!1,d),this.setSelectedState(b,!1,d),this.setCheckedState(b,!1,d),d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeDisabled",a.extend(!0,{},b))):(b.state.disabled=!1,d.silent||this.$element.trigger("nodeEnabled",a.extend(!0,{},b))))},g.prototype.render=function(){this.initialized||(this.$element.addClass(e),this.$wrapper=a(this.template.list),this.injectStyle(),this.initialized=!0),this.$element.empty().append(this.$wrapper.empty()),this.buildTree(this.tree,0)},g.prototype.buildTree=function(b,c){if(b){c+=1;var d=this;a.each(b,function(b,e){for(var f=a(d.template.item).addClass("node-"+d.elementId).addClass(e.state.checked?"node-checked":"").addClass(e.state.disabled?"node-disabled":"").addClass(e.state.selected?"node-selected":"").addClass(e.searchResult?"search-result":"").attr("data-nodeid",e.nodeId).attr("style",d.buildStyleOverride(e)),g=0;c-1>g;g++)f.append(d.template.indent);var h=[];if(e.nodes?(h.push("expand-icon"),h.push(e.state.expanded?d.options.collapseIcon:d.options.expandIcon)):h.push(d.options.emptyIcon),f.append(a(d.template.icon).addClass(h.join(" "))),d.options.showIcon){var h=["node-icon"];h.push(e.icon||d.options.nodeIcon),e.state.selected&&(h.pop(),h.push(e.selectedIcon||d.options.selectedIcon||e.icon||d.options.nodeIcon)),f.append(a(d.template.icon).addClass(h.join(" ")))}if(d.options.showCheckbox){var h=["check-icon"];h.push(e.state.checked?d.options.checkedIcon:d.options.uncheckedIcon),f.append(a(d.template.icon).addClass(h.join(" ")))}return f.append(d.options.enableLinks?a(d.template.link).attr("href",e.href).append(e.text):e.text),d.options.showTags&&e.tags&&a.each(e.tags,function(b,c){f.append(a(d.template.badge).append(c))}),d.$wrapper.append(f),e.nodes&&e.state.expanded&&!e.state.disabled?d.buildTree(e.nodes,c):void 0})}},g.prototype.buildStyleOverride=function(a){if(a.state.disabled)return"";var b=a.color,c=a.backColor;return this.options.highlightSelected&&a.state.selected&&(this.options.selectedColor&&(b=this.options.selectedColor),this.options.selectedBackColor&&(c=this.options.selectedBackColor)),this.options.highlightSearchResults&&a.searchResult&&!a.state.disabled&&(this.options.searchResultColor&&(b=this.options.searchResultColor),this.options.searchResultBackColor&&(c=this.options.searchResultBackColor)),"color:"+b+";background-color:"+c+";"},g.prototype.injectStyle=function(){this.options.injectStyle&&!c.getElementById(this.styleId)&&a('<style type="text/css" id="'+this.styleId+'"> '+this.buildStyle()+" </style>").appendTo("head")},g.prototype.buildStyle=function(){var a=".node-"+this.elementId+"{";return this.options.color&&(a+="color:"+this.options.color+";"),this.options.backColor&&(a+="background-color:"+this.options.backColor+";"),this.options.showBorder?this.options.borderColor&&(a+="border:1px solid "+this.options.borderColor+";"):a+="border:none;",a+="}",this.options.onhoverColor&&(a+=".node-"+this.elementId+":not(.node-disabled):hover{background-color:"+this.options.onhoverColor+";}"),this.css+a},g.prototype.template={list:'<ul class="list-group"></ul>',item:'<li class="list-group-item"></li>',indent:'<span class="indent"></span>',icon:'<span class="icon"></span>',link:'<a href="#" style="color:inherit;"></a>',badge:'<span class="badge"></span>'},g.prototype.css=".treeview .list-group-item{cursor:pointer}.treeview span.indent{margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px}.treeview span.icon{width:12px;margin-right:5px}.treeview .node-disabled{color:silver;cursor:not-allowed}",g.prototype.getNode=function(a){return this.nodes[a]},g.prototype.getParent=function(a){var b=this.identifyNode(a);return this.nodes[b.parentId]},g.prototype.getSiblings=function(a){var b=this.identifyNode(a),c=this.getParent(b),d=c?c.nodes:this.tree;return d.filter(function(a){return a.nodeId!==b.nodeId})},g.prototype.getSelected=function(){return this.findNodes("true","g","state.selected")},g.prototype.getUnselected=function(){return this.findNodes("false","g","state.selected")},g.prototype.getExpanded=function(){return this.findNodes("true","g","state.expanded")},g.prototype.getCollapsed=function(){return this.findNodes("false","g","state.expanded")},g.prototype.getChecked=function(){return this.findNodes("true","g","state.checked")},g.prototype.getUnchecked=function(){return this.findNodes("false","g","state.checked")},g.prototype.getDisabled=function(){return this.findNodes("true","g","state.disabled")},g.prototype.getEnabled=function(){return this.findNodes("false","g","state.disabled")},g.prototype.selectNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setSelectedState(a,!0,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.unselectNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setSelectedState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.toggleNodeSelected=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.toggleSelectedState(a,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.collapseAll=function(b){var c=this.findNodes("true","g","state.expanded");this.forEachIdentifier(c,b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setExpandedState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.collapseNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setExpandedState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.expandAll=function(b){if(b=a.extend({},f.options,b),b&&b.levels)this.expandLevels(this.tree,b.levels,b);else{var c=this.findNodes("false","g","state.expanded");this.forEachIdentifier(c,b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setExpandedState(a,!0,b)},this))}this.render()},g.prototype.expandNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setExpandedState(a,!0,b),a.nodes&&b&&b.levels&&this.expandLevels(a.nodes,b.levels-1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.expandLevels=function(b,c,d){d=a.extend({},f.options,d),a.each(b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setExpandedState(b,c>0?!0:!1,d),b.nodes&&this.expandLevels(b.nodes,c-1,d)},this))},g.prototype.revealNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){for(var c=this.getParent(a);c;)this.setExpandedState(c,!0,b),c=this.getParent(c)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.toggleNodeExpanded=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.toggleExpandedState(a,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.checkAll=function(b){var c=this.findNodes("false","g","state.checked");this.forEachIdentifier(c,b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setCheckedState(a,!0,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.checkNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setCheckedState(a,!0,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.uncheckAll=function(b){var c=this.findNodes("true","g","state.checked");this.forEachIdentifier(c,b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setCheckedState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.uncheckNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setCheckedState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.toggleNodeChecked=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.toggleCheckedState(a,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.disableAll=function(b){var c=this.findNodes("false","g","state.disabled");this.forEachIdentifier(c,b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setDisabledState(a,!0,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.disableNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setDisabledState(a,!0,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.enableAll=function(b){var c=this.findNodes("true","g","state.disabled");this.forEachIdentifier(c,b,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setDisabledState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.enableNode=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setDisabledState(a,!1,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.toggleNodeDisabled=function(b,c){this.forEachIdentifier(b,c,a.proxy(function(a,b){this.setDisabledState(a,!a.state.disabled,b)},this)),this.render()},g.prototype.forEachIdentifier=function(b,c,d){c=a.extend({},f.options,c),b instanceof Array||(b=[b]),a.each(b,a.proxy(function(a,b){d(this.identifyNode(b),c)},this))},g.prototype.identifyNode=function(a){return"number"==typeof a?this.nodes[a]:a},g.prototype.search=function(b,c){c=a.extend({},f.searchOptions,c),this.clearSearch({render:!1});var d=[];if(b&&b.length>0){c.exactMatch&&(b="^"+b+"$");var e="g";c.ignoreCase&&(e+="i"),d=this.findNodes(b,e),a.each(d,function(a,b){b.searchResult=!0})}return c.revealResults?this.revealNode(d):this.render(),this.$element.trigger("searchComplete",a.extend(!0,{},d)),d},g.prototype.clearSearch=function(b){b=a.extend({},{render:!0},b);var c=a.each(this.findNodes("true","g","searchResult"),function(a,b){b.searchResult=!1});b.render&&this.render(),this.$element.trigger("searchCleared",a.extend(!0,{},c))},g.prototype.findNodes=function(b,c,d){c=c||"g",d=d||"text";var e=this;return a.grep(this.nodes,function(a){var f=e.getNodeValue(a,d);return"string"==typeof f?f.match(new RegExp(b,c)):void 0})},g.prototype.getNodeValue=function(a,b){var c=b.indexOf(".");if(c>0){var e=a[b.substring(0,c)],f=b.substring(c+1,b.length);return this.getNodeValue(e,f)}return a.hasOwnProperty(b)?a[b].toString():d};var h=function(a){b.console&&b.console.error(a)};a.fn[e]=function(b,c){var d;return this.each(function(){var f=a.data(this,e);"string"==typeof b?f?a.isFunction(f[b])&&"_"!==b.charAt(0)?(c instanceof Array||(c=[c]),d=f[b].apply(f,c)):h("No such method : "+b):h("Not initialized, can not call method : "+b):"boolean"==typeof b?d=f:a.data(this,e,new g(this,a.extend(!0,{},b)))}),d||this}}(jQuery,window,document);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="::{'hidden-xs' : options.hide_xs}" class="panel panel-{{::options.color}} b">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <span ng-if="::options.glyph">
                <fa name="{{::options.glyph}}" />
            </span>
            {{::data.title}}
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="category-tree"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks 
Venkat

Comment: please share html css content

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I used script in https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

Comment: hi, i have shared an answer, is that helping?

Comment: i used same CSS, but still node icons are appearing left to the main menu

Comment: for the icons, i have used font awesome. Not node icons. Its a different set of icons because it was not provided in the question, therefore can you provide a link of what you have been using as icons? where to find the reference

Comment: can you provide your sample code?

Comment: Updated the question with the code, can you please help me on this

Comment: Check the edited section below in the answer, it's just a simple trick

Comment: This will change title and icons in panel header, not the actual menus rendering in panel body

Comment: How about now? I think better if you play with the code by changing the places. Can you upload a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet. The following are the icon settings which is not necessary, you can replace with your icon set. This is just for demonstration purpose.

```
.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon,
.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m8,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m8 {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon,
.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m8,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m8 {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m5,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m5 {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m5,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m5 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m12,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m12 {
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m12,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m12 {
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m15,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m15 {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m15,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m15 {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```js
$('.tree-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
});
$(function() {
  $('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
})
```

```css
.no-padding {
  padding: 0px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon,
.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m8,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m8 {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon,
.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m8,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m8 {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m5,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m5 {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m5,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m5 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m12,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m12 {
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m12,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m12 {
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m15,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m15 {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m15,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m15 {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style .nav-header .menu-collapsible-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 16px;
  font-size: 9px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style .nav-header {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style>li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style>li a {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style>li:first-child a {}

ul.nav-menu-list-style {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style li .badge,
ul.nav-menu-list-style li .pull-right,
ul.nav-menu-list-style li span.badge,
ul.nav-menu-list-style li label.badge {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

ul.bullets {
  list-style: inside disc
}

ul.numerics {
  list-style: inside decimal
}

.ul.kas-icon-aero {}

ul.kas-icon-aero li a:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 9px;
  content: "\e258";
  padding-right: 8px;
}

span {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tree</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well no-padding">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav nav-list nav-menu-list-style">
            <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header glyphicon-icon-rpad">Bootstrap<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close m5"></span>
                            <span class="menu-collapsible-icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></label>
              <ul class="nav nav-list tree bullets">
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Buttons</label>
                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                    <li><a href="#">Colors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sizes</a></li>
                    <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Forms</label>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="#">Horizontal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vertical</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Responsive</label>
              <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Media Queries</label>
                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
                    <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Mobile Devices</label>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Coding</label>
                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                    <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">HTML DOM</label>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="#">DOM Elements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recursive</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited to the question.

Why don't you swap the icon and the text which you are getting. And then you can use some `margin-left` to your icons. Try the below snippet which is the same thing. But I cannot see it by running on mine.

```html
<div ng-class="::{'hidden-xs' : options.hide_xs}" class="panel panel-{{::options.color}} b">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">    
      <span ng-if="::options.glyph">
      {{::data.title}}
                <fa name="{{::options.glyph}}" />
            </span>

    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="category-tree"></div>
</div>
```